# Create predicates given the last n elements of a list

Tags: prolog

Example:

```
?-lastN([1,2,3,4],3,T).
T = [2,3,4]
```

this is whay i'm write:

```
lastN(L,N,R):- length(L,X), X1 is X-N, lastT(L, N,R).
lastT(L,0,L).
lastT(X,[H|T],L):- X2 is X-1, lastT(T,X2,L).
```

Comment: What is the problem? Notice though you are asking for the `length(L, X)` of an integer, since you call `lastN([1,2,3,4],3,T).` but `L` is the second parameter, not the first (at `lastN(N,L,R)`).

Comment: I don't see a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the question was 'predicate to get last N elements in a list' and this is what you meant to do. It's a simple discarding of the first element after counting how many elements have to be discarded, right? It also does not deal with improper input at all

```
lastN(L,N,R):- length(L,X), X1 is X-N, lastT(L,X1,R).
lastT(L,0,L).
lastT([H|T],X,L):- X2 is X-1, lastT(T,X2,L).
```